# USB DAC not listing as playback device

Tags: usb, audio

I am trying to get a Musical Fidelity V90-AMP to work for playback of music using my Pi. I installed the SqueezePlug image and it otherwise works fine via the analog output.

The problem seems to be that the V90 is not being recognized as a playback device. So far, I have modified the alsa-base.conf file to push USB up in priority but this did not help because I think the USB DAC is not being recognized in the first place.

When I do aplay -l, I get:

```
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lsusb shows the DAC:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 25b0:0012
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x25b0
  idProduct          0x0012
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          115
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength           30
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0
        iTerminal               0
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               1
        iTerminal               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           1
        bDelay                  1 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           3
        bBitResolution         24
        bSamFreqType            3 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        32000
        tSamFreq[ 1]        44100
        tSamFreq[ 2]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0246  1x 582 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress         129
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0003  1x 3 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                5
        bSynchAddress           0
```

What seem to be the relevant lines from dmesg are:

```
[  386.322721] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[  386.469463] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=25b0, idProduct=0012
[  386.469503] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  386.469523] usb 1-1.2: Product: Musical Fidelity V90-AMP
[  386.469544] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Musical Fidelity
[  386.474633] snd-rpi-iqaudio-dac sound: ASoC: CODEC DAI pcm512x-hifi not registered
[  386.474730] snd-rpi-iqaudio-dac sound: snd_soc_register_card() failed: -517
[  386.474779] platform sound: Driver snd-rpi-iqaudio-dac requests probe deferral
```

Any suggestions as to what I need to do to get this thing recognized as a playback device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a kernel and firmware update fixed the problem.  Turns out that even the latest SqueezePlug image has quite a few changes.  All seems to be working well now.

Comment: Could you please mark your answer as correct then.